# Java call with MS Graph to get Sharepoint sites returns 500 error

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have some code that will do a query to find all sites using the java ms graph libraries.

```
        IDriveCollectionPage drives = graphClient.drives().buildRequest().get();
        ISiteCollectionPage sitesPage = graphClient.sites().buildRequest().  get();
```

The first line still works, however the second line has suddenly started to fail with the error :

```
    500 : Internal Server Error
    Cache-Control : no-cache
    client-request-id : 6bc81403-33ca-4aae-84d3-7b711ef12b6b
    Content-Type : application/json
    Date : Mon, 26 Apr 2021 08:10:34 GMT
    request-id : e3004346-4297-4864-9802-cc17b81e875e
    Strict-Transport-Security : max-age=31536000
    Transfer-Encoding : chunked
    Vary : Accept-Encoding
    x-ms-ags-diagnostic : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"UK South","Slice":"E","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"LN2PEPF000039ED"}}
    {
      "error": {
        "code": "generalException",
        "message": "An assertion failed while processing this request",
        "innerError": {
          "code": "assertionFailed",
          "date": "2021-04-26T08:10:34",
          "request-id": "e3004346-4297-4864-9802-cc17b81e875e",
          "client-request-id": "6bc81403-33ca-4aae-84d3-7b711ef12b6b"
        }
      }
    }
```

Checked that the application registration in Azure has NOT changed.
There are a number of other ms graph calls that sill work, as illustrated by the call to one drive.

************** FULL CODE *************************************************

```
package com.example.testsharepoint;

import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialFactory;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialParameters;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ConfidentialClientApplication;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.IAuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.extensions.IGraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.GraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.IDriveCollectionPage;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.ISiteCollectionPage;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

@Component
public class SharepointAdapter {

    private static final transient Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SharepointAdapter.class);
    private String accessToken = null;
    private String clientId = "XXX";
    private String clientSecret = "XXX";
    private String tenantId = "XXX";

    protected final static String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
    public static final String DefaultScope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
    protected Set<String> scopeSet = new HashSet<String>();
    private ConfidentialClientApplication app;
    protected IAuthenticationResult result;

    private IGraphServiceClient graphClient = null;
    private SimpleAuthProvider authProvider = null;


    public SharepointAdapter()
    {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public  void init() throws Exception {
        getUserAccessToken();
    }

    public void getUserAccessToken() throws Exception {

        app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(
                clientId,
                ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret))
                .authority(authority + tenantId + "/")
                .build();

        String[] appScopes = DefaultScope.split(",");
        CollectionUtils.addAll(scopeSet, appScopes);

       ClientCredentialParameters.ClientCredentialParametersBuilder builder = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(scopeSet);
        ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = builder.build();

        if ( log.isDebugEnabled())
        {
            log.debug("{} Getting token...", getLogPrefix());
        }

        CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);

        BiConsumer<IAuthenticationResult, Throwable> processAuthResult = (res, ex) -> {
            if (ex != null) {
                Throwable error = ex.getCause();
                if (error != null) {
                    log.error("{}Error connecting to Microsoft - {}", getLogPrefix(), error.getMessage());
                } else {
                    log.error("{}Error connecting to Microsoft - {}", getLogPrefix(), ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };

        future.whenCompleteAsync(processAuthResult);
        future.join();

        result = future.get();
        if (result == null) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to connect to Microsoft, did not get an authentication token.");
        }

        if ( log.isTraceEnabled())
        {
            log.trace("{}: TOKEN: {}", getLogPrefix(), result.accessToken() );
        }

        String token = result.accessToken();
        authProvider = new SimpleAuthProvider(token);
        // Build a Graph client
        graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .logger(MSLogger.getLogger())
                .buildClient();

        IDriveCollectionPage drives = graphClient.drives().buildRequest().get();

        ISiteCollectionPage sitesPage = graphClient.sites().buildRequest().  get();
    }

    protected String getLogPrefix()
    {
        return "[ Client ID: "+ clientId + "] ";
    }

}
```

Relevant version set:

```
        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR10</spring-cloud.version>
        <springframework.boot.version>2.3.9.RELEASE</springframework.boot.version>
        <microsoft-msal4j-version>1.9.1</microsoft-msal4j-version>
        <microsoft-graph-version>2.10.0</microsoft-graph-version>
        <azure.version>3.2.0</azure.version>
```

Any help gratefully received.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this issue, found the following change made the call successful:

```
        LinkedList<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<Option>();
        requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("search", "*"));
        ISiteCollectionPage sitesPage = graphClient.sites().buildRequest(requestOptions).get();
```

Not sure why the old code suddenly stopped working, but this has fixed it.

Comment: However, I have just noticed that this answer does not work with the beta endpoint.